# How to end program if input == "quit" with many if statements?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break

I want the user to be able to quit this program at any point by typing in "quit".

Is there a way to do this with one instance of a break statement, or do I need to add a break to every "if y ==" statement in my code?

```
fruits = []
notfruits = []
print(fruits)
print(notfruits)

while len(fruits) < 3 or len(notfruits) < 3:   # replaced `and` with `or`
    print("Please enter fruits or notfruits:") #
    y = str(input(": "))                       # moved the input here
    if y == "fruits":
        while len(fruits) < 3:
            x = str(input(": "))
            x = x.strip()
            if x in notfruits:
                print(x + " is not a fruit!")
            elif x in fruits:
                print(x + " is already in the list!")
            else:
                fruits.append(x)
                print(fruits)
    elif y == "notfruits":
         while len(notfruits) < 3:
            x = str(input(": "))
            x = x.strip()
            if x in fruits:
                print(x + " is a fruit!")
            elif x in notfruits:
                print(x + " is already in the list!")
            else:
                notfruits.append(x)
                print(notfruits)
    elif y == "clearfruits":
        del fruits[:]
    elif y == "clearnotfruits":
        del notfruits[:]
    elif y == "quit":
        break
    else:
        print("Not a valid option!")
```

Comment: You can create your own `myInput` function which calls `input` and calls `sys.exit(0)` if it founds "quit" and returns input otherwise. Then you replace all `input`s by `myInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function, use it each time you taker an input, call "exit()" to leave

For example

```
import sys

def check_quit(inp):
    if inp == 'quit':
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: @michael-butscher has the best answere.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping to only need to call the function once, but I just placed it with each instance of user input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

to immediately stop executing further program statements, so something like

```
elif y == "quit":
    import sys
    sys.exit(0)
```

should work.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Comment: used @michael-butscher solution, but your's is the same idea without the function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that both writing a function and using `sys.exit` are overkill for what OP asked, depending whether you're trying to break out of the loop or exit the program entirely

Specifically regarding your question, you can `break` right after your `input()` and it will exit the loop without executing the rest of the run. (BTW, you don't need to cast input to a string, input is a string by default)

```
y = input(": ")
if y.lower() == "quit":
    break    
if y == "fruits":
```

Comment: This breaks the current loop and reverts back to the previous loop. Useful because I wanted to create a "back" step at each loop, but doesn't end the whole program until you get to the first loop and enter "quit". Thank you for answering!

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood your question, the solution breaks out of the `while` loop if put right after the input. Hope it was helpful anyway

Comment: No problem. It was helpful, as I also wanted a way to break the current loop without exiting the whole program.